# ProGuard obfuscation - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getPointer

Tags: java, ant, libgdx, lwjgl, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate a game that I wrote. I slimmed it down to a very basic project to illustrate the problem (the project can be found here: https://github.com/dschneider/libgdx-proguard-test).

You have to install **ant** and run **make desktop** in terminal to compile and obfuscate the project. The following error occurs when trying to run the obfuscated jar afterwards:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getPointer
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1894)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:70)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.b(Sys.java:66)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.c(Sys.java:95)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.<clinit>(AL.java:59)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.openal.OpenALAudio.<init>(OpenALAudio.java:70)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:82)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:64)
at com.libgdxproguard.test.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Am I missing something? When I tell ProGuard to not obfuscate the code, it works afterwards. Apparently something is obfuscated what shouldn't be obfuscated, but I am not sure how to solve this error.

Comment: You could try it with this config: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-maven-archetype/blob/master/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/android/proguard.cfg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native code in `liblwjgl.so` calls back to the Java code of the LWJGL library, using reflection. ProGuard isn't aware of anything that the native code does, so it may remove or rename the classes, fields, and methods, which breaks the reflection. The simplest solution is to tell ProGuard to preserve all of them with their original names:

```
-keep class org.lwjgl.** { *; }
```

The same is happening with `libgdx.so` in the GDX library, so:

```
-keep class com.badlogic.** { *; }
```

You could refine this configuration by figuring out more precisely which classes, fields, and methods need to be preserved.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick! I think it will work that way, I want to preserve everything from those packages actually. I have been using "-keep class org.lwjgl.**" before. Does the asterisk inside the curly braces refer to all methods, fields and classes inside the package?

Comment: @RaceCondition `*;` inside curly braces is short for `<fields>; <methods>;`. See the ProGuard manual > Usage > Class Specifications: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#classspecification